# Is there a way to delete NA in a location column?

Tags: r, na

I have a data set of car crash data where I am gonna analyse them based of their locations. However, I want to clean the data first, How would I go about in removing crashes that have NA in the region column.

Comment: Please provide your data and code, for a better understanding of the problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

your_data_frame %>% 
  filter(!is.na(region_column))
```